# iExplorer unable to start the iPhone listener process error

Tags: windows-7, iphone

When I install [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer) 3.0.1.9 (and run as admin) on Windows 7 I get this error message:

> Unable to start the iPhone listener process. This error may occur because iTunes is not installed.
>
> Error Code: Unable to load DLL 'iTunesMobileDevice.dll': The specified pricedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

I have an iPhone 5.1.1. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you mean "iTunes" instead of "iexplore"?

Comment: No, I mean iexplore http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/

Comment: Ah, OK. Just to be sure, do you have iTunes installed? If yes, have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Comment: Hi, yes I tried.

Comment: No solution? I get same error. 
  `Error Code: Unable to load DLL 'iTunesMobileDevice.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

Answer (score 0):

With iExplorer version 4.3.4.0 (downloaded on 2020-02-25), I had the same issue.

I had installed iTunes from the Windows store.  Uninstalling iTunes and reinstalling it directly from Apple (via https://www.apple.com/itunes/download/win64) solved the problem for me.  (That suggestion came from https://helpdesk.macroplant.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018857234--iPhone-Listener-Process-error-is-appearing-and-I-don-t-see-my-iPhone-or-iPad- .)